# Error Running jar command from shell Script

Tags: shell, sh, aix

I need to Extract the contents of the Jar in to a specific location. When I run the below command to extract jar,it works correctly.

```
jar -xf location/ex.jar
```

The same command I placed inside a script(.sh/.ksh).When I run the script, I get the below error :

```
 jar:  not found.
```

Both the user are same from which I run the script/command. I am using AIX server. 
Thanks for Your help.

Comment: odd that is cannot find it if you are running as same user, are you using the same shell (What does your #! line look like). Guessing that shell has different path set.  Try either adjusting your PATH, or placing the full path to jar in your script.

Comment: Note: Also you can install and use program _unzip_ (jar/war/ear files are actually zip files), but you still have to solve the PATH-problem.

Comment: Look at the difference commandline and shell by performing `echo $PATH` on the commandline and in the script. You should look for the directory with jar (try `which jar`). Perhaps you call the script using crontab, which will not execute settings in your `$HOME/.profile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PATH variable isn't set correctly.

1. Find your java installation : find / -name "java"
2. Add the correct path to your PATH variable : export PATH="$PATH:/location/to/java/jre/bin"

Or, just use unzip /location/ex.jar